# Get the main content from RSS Feeds

Tags: java, android, url, xml-parsing, rss

I've created an application which lists all the feed items in `ListFragment`. My question is how to load the full text from the link. I've tried with `WebView`, but it is loading the complete `URL`. Since `RSS XML` structure does not have any tags related to full/actual content, can anyone give some reference so that I can use it?

This is how I've tried to load the `URL` in `WebView`:

```
    URL = getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_display_news_webview);

    webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

Comment: http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/sport/0/football/rss.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boilerpipe](http://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/) to extract the full text from the url